# How can i solve a 'Semantic Issue'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv

I've download a template [here](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares)

I have XCode 4.6 When I run it I got the following:

```
 + (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
{
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCVMat:cvMat orientation:orientation];
}

+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCVMat:cvMat orientation:0];
}
```

and i got the error

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UIImageOrientation' with an value of type 'int'
```

how do i solve it? Maybe anyone knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about using the `0` value in your second convenience method

Choose a default orientation for when none is given

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat {
     return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCVMat:cvMat orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCVMat:cvMat orientation:0];
}
```

you cant have `orientation:0` because it expects an object of type `UIImageOrientation`. maybe try making it `nil` (not sure if that is allowed) or give it a new default UIImageOrientation